# Single token but multiple platform options

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to wrap my head around the new FCM HTTP V1 API. Following is a payload that includes the message with payload for `android`, and `ios` platforms.

```
{
  "token": "asdf2sdf:asdf",
  "message": {
    "data": {
      "message": "Some custom data message"
    },
    "notification": {
      "title": "title",
      "body": "text"
    },
    "android": {
      "priority": "high",
      "notification": {
        "sound": "sound",
        "icon": "ic_launcher_small",
        "click_action": "FCM_PLUGIN_ACTIVITY",
        "badge": "1"
      }
    },
    "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "5",
        "apns-push-type": "alert"
      },
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "alert": {
            "title": "title",
            "body": "text"
          },
          "sound": "sound",
          "mutable-content": 1,
          "content-available": 1,
          "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY",
          "badge": 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, my the `token` is something that is a single value. It can either be registered for `android` or `iOS`.

My question is, what is the use of `apns` property if my token is registered from `android` or viceversa.

Comment: If you know which platform the token is for then you can customise your payload accordingly, but it is typically simpler not to worry about that and just send the same payload.